# RStudio cannot find fonts to be used in plotting

Tags: r, rstudio

I'm attempting to plot a simple density plot in RStudio. The plot itself shows up, but with no text and this error message:

```
50: In doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler) :
no font could be found for family "Arial"
```

I've tried Googling the answer and several people seem to have had the same problem, without any solutions being found.

I'm running RStudio (version 1.0.153) on a MacBook Pro (High Sierra, 10.13.3)

Here's the full code I am running:

```
lim <- vector()
xn <- vector()
for (j in 1:1000) {
  ek <- rexp(10000,1)
  i <- 1:10000
  xn <- 1/sqrt(i) * sum(ek) - sqrt(i)
  lim[j] <- xn[10000]
}

plot(density(lim))
```

I've already tried changing fonts (Helvetica doesn't work either) and resetting the graphics with `dev.off()`.

Comment: I can't reproduce this error, and I'm not sure what's causing it, but one thing you can try is the `extrafont` package: Follow the [**instructions here**](https://github.com/wch/extrafont) to install the package and to import and register fonts for use with R.

Comment: I installed the package. `install.packages` gives the same warning message as I was getting before. So does `font_import()`

Comment: For what it's worth, everything works just fine when I try knitting the plot (using RMarkdown).

Comment: What happens if you restart your R session and try the plot in an R script?

Comment: Restarting the session doesn't change anything. I've tried doing it in R (not RStudio) as well, but that also appears to make no difference.

Comment: I'm attempting to learn R and have the same problem with High Sierra 10.13.5 and RStudio Version 1.1.453

Answer (score 5):

I had this problem recently using `High Sierra 10.13.5 RStudio 1.1.453 and R 3.5.0`. My plots all showed up without text but worked fine with the same version of R and RStudio on a mac running the previous OS. The command warnings() showed error messages with this text:

> no font could be found for family "Arial"

I found that High Sierra has sometimes disabled fonts, even though they are in /Library/Fonts. There is a new app with the OS called Font Book.app. Some details are [here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8420562).

Looking in the Font Book app, I found that Arial was indeed greyed out and turned off. I chose `enable` from the popup menu and had to restart the computer before it worked on plots in RStudio and R. Restarting the software wasn't enough.

Answer (score 2):

Just want to add a comment in case other users find this help page. I had a very similar issue to OP - `Mac OS Mojave 10.14.5`, `Rstudio 1.1.456` and `R 3.6.0`

Some additional information on [R can not find fonts to be used in plotting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55933524/r-can-not-find-fonts-to-be-used-in-plotting)

All of base R, lattice and ggplot all could not source font family Arial, so I agree it was a system issue not R specific. I had tried:

1. Go to Font Book, Arial was greyed out, reactive, restart - no deal
2. Re-installing all standard fonts in Font Book, restart - no deal
3. Can workaround calling other font families (eg 'Times') but not a durable solution.
4. `extrafont` package and `import_font()` or `font_add()` did not work and don't address the root cause

For me: trick was there are separate Font book libraries both for the computer (/Library/Fonts) and each user (/Users/userid/Library/Fonts) - ensure Arial active in both of those, my user font library was empty for some reason (despite restoring standard fonts) - copied fonts from computer font library & problem solved.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem to the OP following an upgrade to MacOS Catalina Beta 10.15 (19A546d)

I'm running R 3.6.1, RStudio 1.2.1335 with no problems before upgrading MacOS.

I received several related error messages when trying to plot using ggplot.

1. Error in grid.Call(C_textBounds, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label), x$x, x$y, : polygon edge not found
2. No font could be found for family "Arial"

To solve the problem I reinstalled the system default fonts with the following steps:

1. Open the Font Book app
2. File > Restore Standard Fonts...
3. Restart computer

Answer (score 1):

The answer of Brent is very clear already. Just in case that if you don't have the userid folder in your Users path and your userid don't have the access to the Arial font, you may want to try:

```
library(showtext)
font_add(family = "Arial", regular = "Arial.ttf") ## here is the path to the font to add.
showtext.auto()
```

Comment: Please consider adding an explanation and as the question has been answered multiple times and nearly two years old add what makes your answer unique. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Also on a Mac with `RStudio 1.1.463, R 3.5.1` . The problem was fixed by installing updates for my OS (updated to `Mojave 10.14.3`) and restarting my computer.