# R can not find fonts to be used in plotting

Tags: r, macos

I was using R 3.5.2. on Mac Mojave 10.14.4. Since a couple days have problems with text in my standard plots. Drawing plots with ggplot doesn't work either. I'm getting messages saying :

For standard plots :

> Warning messages:
>   1: In doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler) :
>    no font could be found for family "Arial"

For plots with ggplot2 :

> Error in grid.Call(C_textBounds, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label), x$x, x$y,
>   : polygon edge not found

Any suggestions how I can proceed to find the problem and solved are welcome?

The following steps I already have tried :

1. Go to the Font book and reactive disabled font. Restart computer
2. Upgrading R to R 3.6.0.
3. I can use `par(family = "Arial")` as a workaround each time for standard plots, but this won't work for ggplot2.
4. Reinstalled standard fonts in font book.
5. I installed the packages extrafont in R. When typing fonts() all fonts are shown to be installed.

According MacOSX the fonts are alle installed, active and no duplicates present, but I still can't access them with R.

This is the code I'm testing with :

```
x <- seq(1, 10,1)
y <- rnorm(10, 4,1)
plot(y~x)

library(ggplot2)

# Basic normal curve
p  <- ggplot(data.frame(x = c(-4, 4)), aes(x = x)) +
  stat_function(fun = dnorm, size=1.5)
p
```

Answer (score 5):

Parallel to `extrafont`, here is the solution using [`showtext`](https://github.com/yixuan/showtext).

```
library(showtext)
font_add("Arial", "/Library/Fonts/Arial.ttf")  # Use the actual file path
showtext_auto()

x <- 1:10
y <- rnorm(10, 4, 1)
pdf("plot1.pdf")
plot(y ~ x, family = "Arial")
dev.off()

library(ggplot2)
# Basic normal curve
p <- ggplot(data.frame(x = c(-4, 4)), aes(x = x)) +
    stat_function(fun = dnorm, size = 1.5) +
    theme(text = element_text(family = "Arial"))
ggsave("plot2.pdf", p)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `font_import()`? Afterwards, `fonts()` gives me new fonts that I can use (which were not there before).

Afterwards, I was able to edit the font using `family`-attribute in `theme()`:

```
x <- seq(1, 10,1)
y <- rnorm(10, 4,1)
plot(y~x)

library(ggplot2)
library(extrafont)

fonts()
font_import(prompt = TRUE)
fonts()

# Basic normal curve
p  <- ggplot(data.frame(x = c(-4, 4)), aes(x = x)) +
  stat_function(fun = dnorm, size=1.5) + theme(text = element_text(family = "Arial"))
p
```

UPDATE: 
Even without the `extrafont`-package I got it to work.

Comment: I tried your suggestion but nothing changed. Before `font_import()`I have 34 fonts. The amount is the same afterwards. During `font_import()` I get messages like _/Library/Fonts/Arial.ttf : ArialMT already registered in fonts database. Skipping._ Ik can use the `family-attribute in `theme()`with Webdings, but not with Arial.

Comment: Thank you MrH. You had put me on the right track. It seemed the file Arial.ttf was somehow corrupted. I copied it from my other Mac and now it works again.

Answer (score 0):

Suggest putting the suggested lines in the .rprofile file your home directory. If you don't have this file in your home, create one.  It will be executed each time you start an R session. However, this fix only gave me a valid screen image -- when I went to copy and paste the quartz window into another app (e.g. Preview), it did not work.

These two lines, executed from the terminal, fixed the problem. font_add() is not needed.

iMac:~> cd  /Users/MyUserName/Library/Fonts

iMac:Fonts> cp /Library/Fonts/Arial* .