# Why is R not plotting anything and crashes?

Tags: r, macos, apple-m1

Suddenly R is not working properly anymore. Everything that requires some sort of visualization causes R to run infinitely and ultimately to crash. Even the simplest code such as: hist(rnorm(50)) does not provide anything. After a while I get a message: "Terminate R, R is not responding to your request to interrupt processing so to stop the current operation you may need to terminate R entirely".

I use a M1 macbook, installed the most recent version of R (v4.2.1. Apple silicon arm64 build for M1 Macs) and RStudio Desktop (2022.07.1+554). All packages are uptodate. I tried restarting R, reinstalling R and dev.off(). All the other functions work fine.

Does anyone know what to do?

Comment: Try running `hist(rnorm(50))` in R outside of Rstudio. Is the issue happening?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Phil, thanks for your comment. I tried running "hist(rnorm(50))" in R console, again nothing is happening. This might suggest that the problem is situated in R rather than in Rstudio.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to my problem. Apparently R was trying to search for a font to use to display images. When I restarted my computer R gave the error message: "In doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler) :
no font could be found for family "Arial" "

A resolution for this problem is provided elsewhere:
[RStudio cannot find fonts to be used in plotting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48831219/rstudio-cannot-find-fonts-to-be-used-in-plotting)